# Why are my input/output processors in Scrapy not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html).

I want my `desc` field to be a single string normalized to single spaces, and in uppercase.

**dmoz_spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

I tried declaring input/output processors according to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors

**items.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(
            lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()),
            lambda x: x.upper()
        ),
        output_processor=Join()
    )
```

However, my output still turns out like this.

```
{'desc': ['\r\n\t\r\n                                ',
          ' \r\n'
          '\t\t\t\r\n'
          '                                - By David Mertz; Addison Wesley. '
          'Book in progress, full text, ASCII format. Asks for feedback. '
          '[author website, Gnosis Software, Inc.]\r\n'
          '                                \r\n'
          '                                ',
          '\r\n                                '],
 'link': ['http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/'],
 'title': ['Text Processing in Python']}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and Scrapy 1.1.0

I put up my entire code here: https://github.com/prashcr/scrapy_tutorial, so that you can try and modify it as you wish.

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I was expecting the `desc` field to look like this: "- BY DAVID MERTZ; ADDISON WESLEY. BOOK IN PROGRESS, FULL TEXT, ASCII FORMAT. ASKS FOR FEEDBACK. [AUTHOR WEBSITE, GNOSIS SOFTWARE, INC.]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, there is one more place where you can specify the input and output processors to use: in the Item Field metadata.

I suspect the documentation is misleading/wrong (or may be out of date?), because, according to the source code, the `input_processor` field attribute is read [only inside the `ItemLoader` instance](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/loader/__init__.py#L136), which means that you need to use an Item Loader anyway.

You can use a built-in one and leave your `DmozItem` definition as is:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ...

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            loader = ItemLoader(DmozItem(), selector=sel)
            loader.add_xpath('title', 'a/text()')
            loader.add_xpath('link', 'a/@href')
            loader.add_xpath('desc', 'text()')
            yield loader.load_item()
```

This way the `input_processor` and `output_processor` Item Field arguments would be taken into account and the processors would be applied.

---

Or you can define the processors inside a *custom Item Loader* instead of the `Item` class:

```
class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()


class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    desc_in = MapCompose(
        lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()),
        lambda x: x.upper()
    )

    desc_out = Join()
```

And use it to load items in your spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        loader = MyItemLoader(DmozItem(), selector=sel)
        loader.add_xpath('title', 'a/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('link', 'a/@href')
        loader.add_xpath('desc', 'text()')
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: I see. Now that I look at it, I think the second code snippet under "Declaring Input and Output Processor" did imply needing to use an ItemLoader as well though it could've been more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would fix it is to implement a pipeline in your Scrapy project so you don't have to mess with your existing code.

piplines.py

```py
class DmozPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        item['desc'] = ''.join(item['desc'].split()).upper()

    return item
```

And don't forget to activate the pipeline in the settings.py

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html