# Removing brackets from Scrapy json output

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Final part of my code is to load data from my scrapy pipeline to my pandas dataframe.

A sample result is as below:

```
{"Message": ["\r\n", " Profanity directed toward staff.  ", "\r\n Profanity directed toward warden ", "  \r\n  "], "Desc": "https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/nicholsjoseph.jpg"}
```

When loaded to the dataframe the [] brackets are stil in there with "\r\n". A quick search shows me that this is because of encoding and it is quite common for scrapping.

Can anybody give me an idea of a pythonic way to get a rather cleaner output?

I am expecting something like

```
{"Message: "Profanity directed toward staff. Profanity directed toward warden", "Desc": "https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/nicholsjoseph.jpg"}
```

Edited to add item class and spider:

Item.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join


class DeathItem(Item):

    firstName = Field()
    lastName = Field()
    Age = Field()
    Date = Field()
    Race = Field()
    County = Field()
    Message = Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(unicode.strip),
        output_processor=Join())
    Desc = Field()
    Mid = Field()
```

spider.py

```
from urlparse import urljoin
import scrapy
from texasdeath.items import DeathItem


class DeathSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "death"
    allowed_domains = ["tdcj.state.tx.us"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
        for site in sites:
            item = DeathItem()
            item['Mid'] = site.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['firstName'] = site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            item['lastName'] = site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['Age'] = site.xpath('td[7]/text()').extract()
            item['Date'] = site.xpath('td[8]/text()').extract()
            item['Race'] = site.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
            item['County'] = site.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()

            url = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[2]/a/@href").extract_first())
            urlLast = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[3]/a/@href").extract_first())

            if url.endswith(("jpg","no_info_available.html")):
                item['Desc'] = url
                if urlLast.endswith("no_last_statement.html"):
                    item['Message'] = "No last statement"
                    yield item
                else:
                    request = scrapy.Request(urlLast, meta={"item" : item}, callback =self.parse_details2)
                    yield request
            else:        
                request = scrapy.Request(url, meta={"item": item,"urlLast" : urlLast}, callback=self.parse_details)
                yield request

    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        urlLast = response.meta["urlLast"]
        item['Desc'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='body']/p[3]/text()").extract()
        if urlLast.endswith("no_last_statement.html"):
            item["Message"] = "No last statement"
            return item
        else:
            request = scrapy.Request(urlLast, meta={"item": item}, callback=self.parse_details2)
            return request

    def parse_details2(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        item['Message'] = response.xpath("//div/p[contains(., 'Last Statement:')]/following-sibling::node()/descendant-or-self::text()").extract()
        return item
```

I basically want a output in clean text to be loaded to my pandas dataframe. However all the unwanted characters such as: [],\r\n\t to be left out.

Basically for the data to appear such as in the web.

Comment: have you tried converting the json to a python dictionary (eg: `json.loads(...)`)? Doing string replacement is not the right solution if you have valid json data. You should convert it to a python object, modify the data, and then optionally turn it back into json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tweak the way the extracted item field is post-processed. For that `Scrapy` has the [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with input and output processors. In your case, you need the `Join()` and `MapCompose(unicode.strip)`:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    message_in = MapCompose(unicode, unicode.strip)
    message_out = Join()
```

Comment: `MapCompose(unicode.strip)(['\r\n'])` was just trying this part and returned an error, `TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'unicode' object but received a 'str'`.

Comment: @BernardL could you show the spider, the item and the loader definitions? Thanks.

Comment: @BernardL okay, thanks, could you try with `message_in = MapCompose(unicode, unicode.strip)`?

Comment: Problem is the join does not even work, I am still returned with a list.

Comment: @BernardL I think I see the problem - you have to use an Item Loader in your spider. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245846/why-are-my-input-output-processors-in-scrapy-not-working/37246120#37246120.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Seems to be working, but is it right if I passed my item meta into the loader just for a specific part of the scrape?

Comment: @BernardL it is not a big deal, but better use loaders for everything..for consistency reasons mostly.

Comment: After rereading the documentation. Does the suffix '_in' automatically defines the loader for the field? So if I have a Message field, using `Message_in=MapCompose(unicode.strip)` will automatically apply to my Message field?

Comment: @BernardL it should, though I'm not sure whether it case-sensitive or not. Btw, what I often did was to make the default input and output processors to do the join and strip as in the answer - this is a very common procedure - to get rid of the extra space and newlines and join together the text results. Hope you can make it work.